# When selecting an USB extension cable to extend power cord, what are the relevant considerations?

Tags: usb, battery-life, charging

I want to use USB extension cords to extend the USB power cords for my Android device.  What are the factors that could affect normal charging behavior?  (Consider "normal charging behavior" to be charging speed and long-term effects on the device battery when using only the manufacturer power cord/adapter.)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I think that its affected by the voltage on the USB port. Some ports are only .5V while others are 1V.

Comment: You can also download an app called galaxy charging current that will give you the charge rate of the cable. I know not to go too cheap of a cable because it can sometimes take longer to transfer things.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/103772

This cable has received A LOT of good reviews and is made of quality copper and does allow more electricity through to devices!! Check it out :D